# Which functions are re-entrant in Python for signal library processing

Tags: python

Discussing [Signal handlers and logging in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601674/signal-handlers-and-logging-in-python) the question which functions are re-entrant in Python came up in my mind.

The [signal library](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) mention:

> Although Python signal handlers are
>   called asynchronously as far as the
>   Python user is concerned, they can
>   only occur between the atomic
>   instructions of the Python
>   interpreter. This means that signals
>   arriving during long calculations
>   implemented purely in C (such as
>   regular expression matches on large
>   bodies of text) may be delayed for an
>   arbitrary amount of time.

That re-entrance is not typical is pointed out by the [logging library](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

> If you are implementing asynchronous
>   signal handlers using the signal
>   module, you may not be able to use
>   logging from within such handlers.
>   This is because lock implementations
>   in the threading module are not always
>   re-entrant, and so cannot be invoked
>   from such signal handlers.

I'm a little bit confused because the signal library talks about the GIL (global interpreter lock) as ".. between the atomic instructions ..". In this case signals are postponed and executed as soon as the GIL is left/*unlocked*. A kind of signal queue.

That makes sense but it does not matter if the functions which are called by the postponed signal handler are re-entrant because they are not called within the *real* POSIX signal handler with the "re-entrant"-limitation:

> Only a defined list of POSIX C
>   functions are declared as re-entrant
>   and can be called within a POSIX
>   signal handler. IEEE Std 1003.1 lists
>   118 re-entrant UNIX functions you find
>   at https://www.opengroup.org/ (login
>   required).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that what makes the logging module non-reentrant is that it uses a `threading.Lock` (instead of a `RLock`) to synchronize several threads logging to the same handlers (so messages don't get interweaved).

This means that if a logging call which has acquired a lock is interrupted by a signal handler and that signal handlers tries to log it will deadlock forever waiting for the previous `acquire` to be released.

These locks have nothing to do with the GIL by the way, they are "user created" locks to put it some way, the GIL is a lock used by the interpreter (an implementation detail).

Comment: I've checked Python 2.7.1 release and your assumption is wrong. Check the `_acquireLock()` function in http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Lib/logging/__init__.py?revision=86833&view=markup

Comment: I stand corrected, it is a actually `RLock`. Thanks for digging it up. However, according to the docs, the implementation might not always be re-entrant: "This is because lock implementations in the threading module are not always re-entrant" (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#thread-safety)

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my question. We can summerise that each module that uses the threading library is not re-entrant in sense of be used in a *real* POSIX signal handler. But does not Python postpone signal processing ?

Comment: Even if python postpones signal processing until the next interpreter "tick" (when any pure C functions will have finished), if a signal handler calls a non-reentrant python function which has acquired a lock it will deadlock. This is because that "tick" can occur between two atomic operations of a non-reentrant *python* function. The signal docs just say that a python signal handler won't interrupt a *C* function (since signal processing is delayed until the next interpreter tick) but it can interrupt a non-reentrant *python* function. I'm not sure if I've explained myself well, sorry.

Comment: For me it's clear. The postponed signal handler callback function is running in the main thread, where the GIL is. If a (R)Lock'ed function is called within GIL's main thread context, a task switch can not occur in order to unlock that called function. We run in a deadlock. -- Do we know which functions/modules are (R)Lock'ed in order to prevent a deadlock within the signal handler ? -- Not really, but all function with _one_ opcode are atomic (=re-entrant) in sense of GIL. Is a code review the one and only possibility for the others ?

Answer (score 1):

Some people might prefer to listen for signals using pselect() / ppoll() / a Linux signalfd.  However, pselect() / ppoll() are not available in the python `select` module.

Some event loops claim to support signals.  If you are considering using an event loop, you could look at its documentation.  For example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#unix-signals

Some event loops, like the built-in asyncio module, are currently implemented using signal.set_wakeup_fd().  This is buggy.  See the heading below.

Otherwise, to answer the letter of your question: `os.write()`.  You can then use the [self-pipe trick](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html).

```
import os
import fcntl
import errno

(sigint_write_pipe, sigint_read_pipe) = os.pipe()
fcntl.fcntl(sigint_write_pipe, fcntl.SET_FL,
            os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_CLOEXEC)

def handle_sigint():
    try:
        os.write(sigint_write_pipe, b'\0')
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno = errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            pass  # pipe is already full. no problem.
        else:
            raise

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)

# Now listen to sigint_read_pipe, using your preferred
# select() / poll() / event loop etc
...
```

---

There are several ways a function could achieve async-signal safety.  `os.write()` is the most likely function, to meet the first criteria:

1. Functions implemented purely in C. Because the python-level signal handler does not interrupt C functions.
2. Python functions that do not access mutable global variables.
3. Python functions that access mutable global variables, where their "invariants" are never temporarily broken.  E.g. a single variable which no invariant applies to.

In many cases, async-signal safety will be considered a private implementation detail, not a public guarantee of future behaviour.  This is true even in C.  The official python documentation does not mention your concern.  So we should not trust python documentation as a guide here.

### signal.set_wakeup_fd()

If you still believe the python documentation, there is a [second option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.set_wakeup_fd) that is "commonly used".  Pass a pipe to `signal.set_wakeup_fd()`, and poll the other end of the pipe.  This lets you detect when your program has been interrupted by a signal.  It does not let you detect what the signal was, because there could have been more than one, and they could overflow the pipe buffer and be lost.