# Python Kill all subprocesses if one of them is finished

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I have a python code that is running other scripts with multiple instances using `subprocess.Popen` and wait for them to  finish with `subprocess.Popen().wait()`.
Everything works fine, however I want to kill all subprocesses if one of them is terminated. Here is the code that I use to run multiple instances with python subprocess package

```
import ctypes
import os
import signal
import subprocess

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")


def set_pdeathsig(sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    def callable():
        return libc.prctl(1, sig)

    return callable


if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = []
    for i in range((os.cpu_count() * 2) - 1):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', "pythonscript_i_need_to_run/"], preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM))
        procs.append(proc)
    procs.append(subprocess.Popen(["python", "other_pythonscript_i_need_to_run"], preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM)))
    for proc in procs:
        proc.wait()
```

The `set_pdeathsig`  function is for killing the children if parent is killed. Long story short I need to kill all children if one is killed. How can I do it ?

*** NOTE ***
When I try to kill the parent when one child is dead with
`os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)` it doesn't kill the original parent script. Also I tried to kill by group pid but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Is solution of killing other when any child is finished (so killed or naturally ended) is suitable for you?

Comment: Another solution can be killing the parent when the child is terminated as the other way around is handled and I will get what I need . But I dont know if its an acceptable way of doing it

Comment: Do you have `signal.pthread_sigmask`?

Comment: @pilcrow nope what is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix and Unix-like Operating System has `SIGCHLD` signal which is send by OS kernel. This signal will be sent to parent process when child process terminated. If you have no handler for this signal, `SIGCHLD` signal will ignored by default. But if you have a handler function for this signal, you tell the kernel “hey I have a handler function, when child process terminated please trigger this handler function to run”

In your case, you have many child process, if one of them killed or finished its execution(by `exit()` syscall) kernel will send a `SIGCHLD` signal to the parent process which is your shared code.

We have a handler for `SIGCHLD` signal which is `chld_handler()` function. When one of the child process terminated, `SIGCHLD` signal will be sent to parent process and `chld_handler` function will triggered to run by OS kernel. (This named is signal catching)

In this function `signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD,chld_handler)` we tell the kernel, “i have handler function for `SIGCHLD` signal, don’t ignore it when child terminated”. In `chld_handler` function which is run when `SIGCHLD` signal was sent, we call `signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)` function that we tell the kernel, “hey I have no handler function, ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal”  we do that because we do not need that anymore since we killing other childs with `p.terminate()` looping the `procs`.

All code would be like below

```
import ctypes
import os
import signal
import subprocess

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")


def set_pdeathsig(sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    def callable():
        return libc.prctl(1, sig)

    return callable

def chld_handler(sig, frame):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
    print("one of the childs dead")
    for p in procs:
         p.terminate()
    
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD,chld_handler)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = []
    for i in range((os.cpu_count() * 2) - 1):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', "pythonscript_i_need_to_run/"], preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM))
        procs.append(proc)
    procs.append(subprocess.Popen(["python", "other_pythonscript_i_need_to_run"], preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM)))
    for proc in procs:
        proc.wait()
```

Also there are much more detail about SIGCHLD signal and python signal library and also zombie process, i do not tell all the thing here because there are so many detail, and i am not expert all the deep knowledge now

I hope above informations give you some insight. If you think i am wrong somewhere, please correct me

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are doing here ?

Comment: Ah sorry, i will edit my answer

Comment: Slight race condition here, I think, if a child process terminates before a newborn child's _Popen_ representation is appended to `procs`.  In that case, the newborn child will not be killed inside `chld_handler`. For practical purposes that may not matter if PDEATHSIG is working, though, depending on your requirements, that may not be good enough.

Comment: Good point, race condition can be, i have an idea for this situation. We can block the `SIGCHLD` signal using `signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, [signal.SIGCHLD])` before the appending to Popen objects to `proc`, and after appending all the Popen objects to `proc`, we can unblock the `SIGCHLD` signal using `signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_UNBLOCK, [signal.SIGCHLD])`

Comment: Blocking signal means: "Hey kernel i have `SIGCHLD` handler, if child process terminate, don't send me SIGCHLD signal, keep it. I'll tell you when you will send it to me ".   

Unblocking signal means: "Hey kernel if you kept the `SIGCHLD` signal, now send it to me"

Comment: @veysel, yes. I’d recommend `sigwait` with SIG_BLOCK, rather than unblocking. However it is moot for the OP:  they don’t have `pthread_sigmask` on their python.

Comment: @pilcrow, Different solution, it is good approach too, no need SIGCHLD handler. I get your recommendation. Maybe you can share your recommend coding

Answer (score 1):

Signal *delivery* (in python, that is using user-defined `signal.signal()` handlers) is sometimes race-prone.  It's easy to code a solution that works most of the time, but may yet miss a signal that arrives just before or just after you are prepared to deal with it.

(For reliable delivery as an I/O event, the venerable [self-pipe trick](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) may be [implemented in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64278892/132382).)

Signal *acceptance* is another approach, in which you SIG_BLOCK a signal to hold it pending when generated, and then accept it with the `signal` module's [`sigwait()`, `sigwaitinfo()`, or `sigtimedwait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.sigwait) when you're ready to do so.  There's no chance of missing the signal here, but you must remember that basic UNIX signals do not queue up:  only one signal of each type will be held pending for acceptance regardless of how many times that signal was generated.

For your problem, that would look something like this, *assuming your implementation supported [`signal.pthread_sigmask()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.pthread_sigmask)*:

```
def main():
    signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, [signal.SIGCHLD])

    ... launch children ...

    signal.sigwait([signal.SIGCHLD])
    # OK, at least one child terminated
    ... terminate other children ...
```