# Handling Signals in Python Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I have a threaded application written in Python, and whenever an interrupt is received via **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** or sometimes with kill, the application will hang. A stack trace is presented from one thread, but the application remains in the foreground, and I usually have to background it with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** then attempt to kill it.

What is the proper way of handling signals and keyboard interrupts inside of a threaded application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you set `newthread.daemon = True` before starting each thread, the threads will automatically be killed when the main thread exits. That's not precisely what you were asking, but from what you've described, it sounds like it could be worth knowing.

Comment: Then, I suppose, the question becomes does the main thread receive Ctrl+C and other signals by default? **EDIT:** This question is answered by @shanked 's post.

Comment: just remember: "Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly." https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html and https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html

Answer (score 5):

The way I worked around this issue was to make a module that could kept a list of threads. The module also had a method that killed every thread in that list. I registered this method to be called when the `SIGINT` signal was received. Lastly, I created a wrapper class for `Thread` that would automatically add the created instance to the list of threads.

Comment: 1) Didn't know it existed. 2) The `Thread` wrapper already existed to do some other things that were not relevant to this question. That being said, the process is still the same.

Answer (score 5):

[CPython Threading: Interrupting](http://snakesthatbite.blogspot.com/2010/09/cpython-threading-interrupting.html) covers what happens to signals in Python threads, and various solutions to your problem.  It is a good read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) and continue reading here [Signal handlers and logging in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601674/signal-handlers-and-logging-in-python) about possible pitfalls.

In order to catch `Ctrl+C` actions from the user you have to profice a [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) handler for `SIGINT`.

Within the signal handler *notify* (message queues or RLock synchronized attribute access) your threads to shutdown, or what ever you intent to do.

Comment: I did not know about the GIL interaction (or non-interaction) With signals. That explains some behaviors I have run into.