# Handling a SIGTERM when blocked in Queue.Queue.get()

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, signals

I have a program that is normally blocked reading a `Queue.Queue`. In the program I defined a Signal handler for `SIGTERM`, however it seems to ignore it.

With other programs I have that are not blocked by a Queue this method works.

Is there a way to capture the `SIGTERM` ? I know that it can be solved adding a `timeout` however that increases CPU usage and I can not afford that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no way around it but using the `timeout` in an endless loop, or probably using an alternative implementation of `queue.Queue` (I don't know if there is any). You are not alone with this problem; I have hit it, and a few other people ([1](http://snakesthatbite.blogspot.com/2010/09/cpython-threading-interrupting.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616361/handling-signals-in-python-threads), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610545/python-how-to-kill-threads-blocked-on-queue-with-signals)) hit it also.

I am sure you know how to implement the polling, but I thought I would chip in my solution:

```
while 1:
    try:
        new_item = my_queue.get(timeout=1.0)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I was doing that, but with a timeout=OneYear. However, every now and then the program uses 1% of CPU, and I have thousands of them running. One day I randomly found that with python 3 this problem is solved, however I have to stick to 2.7.